# RVMRC file, local and server, how to manage this with capistrano deployment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano, rvm

I'm a little confused how I can have different versions of .rvmrc files on my local laptop and on my server when I am using capistrano for deployment.

Since it pulls from my GIT, how can I manage both files?

Answer (score 1):

I just add it to my .gitignore after I pull it down the first time.

Comment: Its also worth pointing out I don't usually use RVM on a production server, since it typically is only serving up a single application.  That said, there's plenty of people who do, so its mainly a matter of preference.